# MonogDB - Replication - can two Nodes write?

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding, failover, mirroring

I have two Servers in action with loadbalancing. To ensure redundancy and failover security I need to implement some kind of mirroring.

However both of these Servers need to be able to write and not only one ( = not Master-Slave).

Is this possible with MongoDB?

Sharding is not a solution because I would lose half the data when a server crashes.

Replication is not a solution because one of the Servers is unable to write/update the DB on the other service.

Comment: You would need at least three nodes. However, the third node can be configured as ARBITER. The arbiter does not store any data, it only takes part in electing the PRIMARY. Data can be written only at the PRIMARY node.

Comment: I understand that I need an abiter. But is it possible to have the Replica Set stored on both Servers? Primary and Secondary i mean. So if the primary dies, that the secondary can still access the data

Comment: That is exactly the purpose of a replica set.  You need a majority of the nodes available in order to elect a primary, which is why you need at least 3 nodes.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/

Comment: Yes, when the primary goes down then the remaining secondaries elect a new primary - provided the **majority of all nodes** are reachable.

Comment: Ok perfect. The next problem I have is that both Servers need to be able to handle request, meaning that both need to be able to write to this Replica Set. Because as far as I know only the primary is able to write

Comment: Correct, only the primary can write. You need to connect to the replica set like this: `mongodb://user:password@server-1:27017,server-2:27017/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=replicaSetName` Then the client will connect to the primary and automatically reconnect to new primary if needed.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thank you very much. I was thinking way too complicated. :)